# How to find out why Fedora will not resume

Tags: fedora, suspend

I have a Fedora 17 desktop system running the latest 64-bit kernel which will not go to sleep properly.  I know this because the fan continues to run after the screen has blanked - further the system will not restart when I repeatedly whack the keyboard with my fists.  Smashing it against the sideboard also has no effect.

If I shut the machine down it will wake successfully on a light keypress.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to how to come to a diagnosis for this as there seem to be many users experiencing this issue but for a wide range of reasons.

Comment: What type of computer do you have it running on?

Comment: AMD Phenom II X4 945 Processor x 4 4Gb RAM - Do you want the motherboard details too ?  IIRC its an NVidia Chipset - I have an ATI Graphics Adapter

Comment: Well, I meant the brand, actually. I had an HP computer, and because they use some proprietary drivers which Fedora was unable to acquire, it had a similar issue. It would go to sleep, but wouldn't wake up. Fortunately, it booted/shut down so fast it wasn't really an issue.

Comment: I see - its a home build

Comment: Ah, well it's probably not the same issue, then. That's actually a good thing, it means you may have a chance at fixing it!

Comment: I am not so sure - the posts I have seen paint a very gloomy picture